# Division and modulo on unsigned integers with 6 registers

Tags: assembly, modulo, integer-division, unsigned-integer, integer-arithmetic

I have to find log time algorithm (for a virtual machine) using maximally 6 registers (a,b,c,d,e,f) to divide two unsigned integers N1 and N2( [both are >=0] positive or 0) where if divider is 0 than result is 0 and modulo operation.

- div ->  N1/N2
- mod -> N1 % N2

with commands like

- RESET a -> a =0
- ADD a b  -> a = a+b
- SUB a b  -> a = max(0,a-b)
- SHR a -> a=floor(a/2)
- SHL a -> a=floor(a*2)
- INC a -> a+=1
- DEC a -> a=max(0,a-1)
- JUMP j -> jump to j-th line
- JZERO x j -> if x is 0 than jump to k+j
- JODD x j -> if x is odd than jump to k+j

Are there any algorithms that can help me ?

I can only check if value in reg is ODD or ZERO.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saturating-subtract and `jzero` allows compare for less-than-or-equal (or greater-than), so you can implement the C version of njuffa's answer on [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding/32443307#32443307)  which produces quotient and remainder. Since you have non-saturating add, you can implement the wrapping add (and then do manual carry-out detection by checking for wraparound, as Nathan does it in C.)

`jodd` lets you test the low bit, like `if (x&1)`, which would let you implement the standard multiply algorithm as well.  So if you had a division algorithm that only gave you a quotient, you could do `remainder = dividend - quotient*divisor` with a log-time multiply.

---

Other binary division Q&As:

- [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding/19780781#19780781)  -another answer on the same Q&A, this time using shifts to "align" the most significant bit of the divisor with the dividend before proceeding with schoolbook long division.  But it's not clear it's safe without extended-width integers.
- [Logarithmic time integer division using bit shift addition and subtraction only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326270/logarithmic-time-integer-division-using-bit-shift-addition-and-subtraction-only)
- [How can I use bit shifting to replace integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850665/how-can-i-use-bit-shifting-to-replace-integer-division)
- [Divide by 10 using bit shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts/34275429#34275429) does a multiply in every step, which is only good if you have a fast multiply, or for known constants with few bits set so it only takes a couple shift/add.  Another advantage is not requiring a right-shift, but you do have a right shift.  (Unlike some toy ISAs)

Comment: Thank you for help :)!